# How to set UISearchBar text before its view controller has appeared?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView and UISearcBar in it.  The UISearchBarDelegate is  connected.  Its called SCOrdersVC:

```
//SCOrders.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SCOrdersVC : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end
```

From a different view controller, I want to set SCOrdersVC up with text already in the search bar (not placeholder text).  What I've tried to do is something like this:

```
//setup SCOrdersVC
SCOrdersVC *detailVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:ordersVCString];
detailVC.searchBar.text = customer.name;
```

But the search bar remains empty when it appears.  How is it supposed to be done?

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, instead of trying to set the text directly, I created a public property in SCOrdersVC called searchBarText.  I set this property externally, and in the viewWillAppear:animated method of SCOrdersVC, I set the search bar's text here from self.searchBarText.  This works and when the view appears, the cells are filtered based on the text I set.